# Inkscape command line - possible to set the antialias option?

Tags: inkscape

How do I set this "Antialias" export option on the inkscape CLI? (this is in the "Export Format Options" window).

[image: inkscape export options]

I can use the Inkscape cli to convert a SVG to a PNG like this:

```
inkscape --export-type=png -o out.png -w 1024 -h 1024 in.svg
```

But I couldn't spot anything on the [inkscape man page](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html) that would let me change these export format options. Could it be one of the `--actions`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this will be added in version 1.4 of inkscape, which as of now (March 2024) needs to be compiled manually. It's not in the linux ppa 1.3 version yet either.

Have compiled and tested, works well.

The new `--export-png-antialias` command line option, which you can set to 0 (none) to 3 (best)

Here is the source code showing the new version:

https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/master/src/actions/actions-output.cpp?ref_type=heads#L315